# Drop on the position. Pure Javascript/ HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently doing my final year project that need to develop a web. 
I'm currently developing to drag a picture into a div and make a copy inside of it in the position I dropped. I succeed to get the coordinates of clientX and clientY but unable to drop on that coordinates. Any ideas on how to drop on it by using Javascript and HTML5 ?

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

   ev.preventDefault();
   window.alert( ev.clientX + ',' + ev.clientY);
   var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
   var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
   ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
   ev.stopPropagation();
   return false;
   
   
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  
  width:500px;height:500px;padding:10px;border:5px solid #aaaaaa;float:left;

}
```

```html
 <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event) " > Drop here </div>

       <img id="drag1" src="images/shoe.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100">
       <img id="drag2" src="images/LZK-Logo.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100">
```

div1 is the place that I want dropped my drag1 and drag2 on. Just I could not fix the position problem. Any idea ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the position of your nodeCopy.

```
var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
nodeCopy.setAttribute("style","position:absolute; top:" + ev.clientY + "px; left:" + ev.clientX + "px;");
ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
```

with this the left upper corner of your image is positioned where your mouse was when you dropped the image.